# Custom database table for plugin not creating on activation

Tags: plugins, database, dbdelta

Let me start by saying I know there are other posts about this, and a lot of documentation is available for this topic, but none of these resources have helped me to solve my issue.

I'm a beginner at creating plugins for WordPress. This is my first, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but everything I have read says this should be working.

The plugin activates no problem, my menu shows up, etc. But the following does not create a new table in the database.  I removed everything besides the id just to see if it was the SQL syntax, still no results.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'pf_rb_install' );      
function pf_rb_install() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'pf_parts';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE '$table_name' (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            PRIMARY KEY (id)
            ) $charset_collate;";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta( $sql );    
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated version of `pf_rb_install()`.

In the table creation SQL, `$table_name` should not be in quotes. The quotes should have triggered an error which would appear in PHP's `error.log` file. Also, there should be two spaces after the `PRIMARY KEY  (id)` portion of the SQL statement.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'pf_rb_install' );
function pf_rb_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'pf_parts';
    $pf_parts_db_version = '1.0.0';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    if ( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$table_name}'" ) != $table_name ) {

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
                        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
                        ) $charset_collate;";

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
        add_option( 'pf_parts_db_version', $pf_parts_db_version );
    }
}
```

The code also has a version number added which will help if modifications are made to the database schema in the future. Finally, a check was added so that the database creation code is only run if the table does not exist. More on creating custom tables can be found in the Codex article [Creating Tables with Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins).

Comment: YES! this did the trick thank you, I did actually have it checking if there was already a table with the same name but had removed it during troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `SQL` statement is a little off. Try this:

```
function pf_rb_install() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'pf_parts';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            PRIMARY KEY  (id)
            )
            COLLATE $charset_collate";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta( $sql );    
}
```

Note: `PRIMARY KEY` **MUST** have two spaces after it.