# dbDelta not creating table (yes, once more)

Tags: sql, dbdelta

I KNOW there are other posts relating to my issue, i read all of them and tried to see if the answer would change and tried a few ones, but I can't seem to create my table using it.

Here's my code (function is in object) and my sql querry:

```
public static function mq_install(){
    global $wpdb;
    require_once(constant('ABSPATH') . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'zebra_musiquote';


    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . "(
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        from tinytext NOT NULL,
        artist tinytext NOT NULL,
        song tinytext NOT NULL,
        quote text NOT NULL,
        url tinytext NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) ".$charset_collate.";";
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
```

Any suggestions? I'm desperate.

Comment: You're using `$wpdb->prefix` and `$wpdb->get_charset_collate()` without creating `$wpdb`. You're missing `global $wpdb;`.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I declared it somewhere else in the object, but I added it within the function, and still no table. Any other idea?

Comment: How are you triggering `my_install()`? register_activation_hook? [Here's a simple example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/271311/2807) that I know works.

Comment: I call it from my plugin's main object with this line of code:
    `register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('Zebra_Mq', 'mq_install'));`